# XMLHttpRequest is deprecated. What to use instead?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Trying to use a pure JS approach to check if I have a valid JS image url. I am getting a warning that `XMLHttpRequest` is deprecated. What is a better way to do this?

```
urlExists(url) {
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    if (http.status !== 404) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: What environment/browser are you getting the warning in?

Comment: Read the complete warning you got

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternatives for Javascript Synchronous XMLHttpRequest (as timing out in Safari)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076614/alternatives-for-javascript-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-as-timing-out-in-safari)

Comment: This is the simplest usage of asynchronous XMLHttpRequest.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're probably getting a message that the **synchronous use** of XMLHttpRequest is deprecated (because of its harmful effect on the user experience; it freezes the page while waiting for a response). I can assure you that proper **asynchronous** use of that API is not deprecated whatsoever.

Here's some example code for the correct use:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.status) // do something; the request has completed
    }
}
xhr.open("HEAD", "http://example.com") // replace with URL of your choosing
xhr.send()
```

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the warning was that in `http.open('HEAD', url, false);` you put a third argument (async) as `false`. As per the https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#synchronous-flag it should be set to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is probably because you are tyring to do a synchronous request.

Answer (score -1):

[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is deprecated, because the Fetch API replaced its place since 2015. Officially deprecated in 2023.

```js
await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST", // GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
    mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, same-origin
    cache: "no-cache", // default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }, extra options);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
If something is deprecated, mozilla is way find replacement specifically for HTTP Related areas.